# Why Microsoft Graph delivers an ItemNotFound although the path is correct

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Hello helpful community.
I am looking for a few days now for a solution to this problem.

There is a SharePoint site with a document library inside that looks like this:
https://myTenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite/myLibrary/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Over the browser this works fine, I can see and open the data in the library.
When I try to get the data over MS Graph the result is ItemNotFound:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/myTenant.sharepoint.com:/sites/mySite:/lists/myLibrary/items

The rights of the enterprise application in Azure are Files.Read.All and User.All.
These rights are for other tenants sufficient for the purpose.

The question is: What is different about this tenant, that the Graph URL cannot be resolved?

Thank you very much for any tip.

Best Regards
psafi

I tried adding Sites.Read.All to the permissions in Azure.
Also tried in Microsoft Graph Explorer:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/myTenant.sharepoint.com:/sites/mySite:/lists
and got an empty array of sites.

Comment: Does GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/myTenant.sharepoint.com:/sites/mySite return site's detail?

Comment: When I GET the site's details, the return is 200, eveything is there.

Answer (score 0):

The graph API does not support the use of a site's webUrl, you should use a site's unique identifier (i.e. site ID).

You can use the following APIs to list the site IDs corresponding to your site:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*
```

[image]

List children of a driveItem:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site id}/drive/root/children
```